# How to install pyxdg in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install **pyxdg** to **anconda** with `python 3.6` using the following command:

```
conda install -c auto pyxdg
```

I get the following error message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python=3.6
  - pyxdg -> python=2.7
```

I tried to remove **pyxdg** from **python2.7**  using the command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove pyxdg
```

But still getting the same **UnsatisfiableError** message mentioned above.
What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo pip3 install pyxdg`?

Comment: No I have not, I want to install this to the anaconda environment, will this work for me? @J-Eubanks

Comment: @HarisKhan conda makes use of pip just fine in virtual environments

Answer (score 0):

I'd really recommend making a conda environment for the task.

Simply

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
```

(where py36 is whatever you name it)

then you can swap to it by doing

```
source activate py36
```

running the install

```
conda install -c auto pyxdg
```

installs correctly for me.

You can then leave anytime by typing

```
source deactivate
```

Not these commands are different on windows (you dont need to type source at all), but it looks like you are using linux.